# Appending an object into array where the array is stored in a dictionary using Swift

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary that has two sections to it. There is a section type Int with value 0 and another section of value 1. In section 0 I want to have an array of Salons. Where Salons is a custom object. Section 1 will also have an array of salons.

Here is the code:

```
func getListOfSalons() -> NSDictionary {

    //I create the dictionary here.
    var dictionary = [Int:[Salon]]();

    //I got to my repo to get an Array holding Salon Objects
    let salonsArray = self.repository.getListOfSalons();

    var count = 0;
    var section = 0;

    //I then iterate through salonsArray to get each salon
    for salon in salonsArray {

        //This code will determine when to switch to new section
        //Ultimately there will only be 3 salons in Secion 0
        if(count > 3 && section == 0){
            section += 1;
        }

        dictionary[section]?.append(salon);
        count += 1;
    }

    return dictionary;
}
```

The problem that I am currently having is that the dictionary always has 0 elements. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you check if salonsArray is actually populated when your loop uses it? How is self.repository.getListOfSalons() implemented?

Comment: have you debugged "salonsArray"? is it an [Saloon] with count > 0?

Answer (score 0):

This code is what you need:

```
func getListOfSaloons() -> NSDictionary {
    var salonsArray = self.repository.getListOfSalons();
    var dictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    var count = 0;
    var section = 0;

    for salon in salonsArray {      
        if(count > 3 && section == 0){
            section += 1;
        }
        if dictionary[section] == nil {
            dictionary[section] = NSMutableArray()
        }
        var salons = dictionary[section] as! [Salon]
        salons.append(salon)
        dictionary[section] = salons
    }
    count += 1;
    return dictionary;
}
```

**Explanation:**

You init dictionary in this way:

```
 var dictionary = [Int:[Salon]]();
```

This instruction create an object with no elements.
So, iterating:

```
 dictionary[0]?.append(salon)
```

what happens?

```
dictionary[0]    => is nil
?.append(salon)  => will never executed
```